# Normal maps in 3dsMax - OgreMax - how to view associated tangent vectors?

Tags: shaders, ogre, 3dsmax, normal-mapping

Reading [this](http://www.polycount.com/forum/showthread.php?t=68173) post I found out that 3dsMax might not use the same tangents when rendering normal mapped objects. In my case, I was using Ogre and OgreMax to analyze results and they were very inconsistent with what Max was showing. I am able to "colour map" the tangent space in Ogre using shaders, but in Max I can't find out how it is computed wrt to the actual geometry. I also posted the question on the Ogre forums, but nobody answered. Has anyone encountered such an issue up until now? How did you go around it?

For further information, [this](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=69253) is the Ogre post.

Comment: No need to answer this question any more. 3dsmax textures need to be flipped (symmetry operator) over the u and the v axes in succession. This actually puts the right orientation in the output tangent vector field.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but I think you should add your comment as an answer for future visitors' reference. (It's perfectly OK to answer your own questions and someone else might have this misunderstanding.)